# Difference between ArrayAdapter and ListAdapter in Android?

Tags: java, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I know that ListAdapter is an interface and ArrayAdapter is a class. So we can only instantiate ArrayAdapter. I met up a code

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songNames);
```

But I was able to do the same thing with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songsArray);
```

So I want to know, in what exact places do we need ListAdapter ?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not related to Android. But a general Java question.

When you use `ListAdapter` as the type for your variable, you are really interested in the interface. You may not be interested in calling some specific method of `ArrayAdapter<String>` not available in `ListAdapter`. That is mainly because you will just assign the adapter as the list adapter for the view.

You may use the precise type of `ArrayAdapter<String>` if you really need to call some specific methods.

It all depends on your use case.

Answer (score -1):

**BaseAdapter**
Its a very generic adapter that allows you to do pretty much whatever you want.
It’s a base class of all adapter.

**ArrayAdapter**
            Its a more complete implementation that works well for data in arrays or ArrayLists.
            Similarly,there is a related CursorAdapter that you should use if your data is in a Cursor.
            Both of these extend BaseAdapter